# What does the phrase "Lying my way from you" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

It's the title of the song by linkin park. 
Well, I can guess by the context, what it means, but I can't quite understand whether it's some grammar construction, or unique phrase. 
Lyrics: 
http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/linkinpark/lyingfromyou.html

Comment: Interpretation of lyrics is OT.

Comment: Okay, and what does it mean? OT

Comment: @DeuS7, OT means off-topic.

Comment: @Kris, Off-topic? Really? What is not then? I didn't ask to explain me the lyrics, I just wanted to know the origins of the phrase. Well, are you saying, that I should have just asked what the phrase meant? Without giving you the context? Well, I bet if I do that, you'll point out that I didn't provide you with context.

Comment: Although "Lying one's way (to something)" has been used occasionally by some, it's not an established idiom AFAIK. Such expressions do find their way into literary works such as poetry and lyrics, and sometimes in formal writing as well. To get an idea, consider: "... lying one's way out of a situation to avoid taking responsibility and feeling guilty." "Life also has easy ways to sneak out of awful predicaments. Lying one’s way to be cleared of a harsh punishment is on(e) of the better examples used by everyone at one time or another." HTH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a very unique way of saying that *he is lying to push the person away* or even that *he is lying so that the person will push him away*.
It's a very unusual sentence construction and the songwriter has taken some poetic/artistic license with the phrasing.